# Insert timestamp data into MySql database from R

Tags: r

I want to insert data from an R dataframe into a MySql table.
Everything works fine except the column geburtstage which is of the type timestamp.
The class of the column geburtstage in the dataframe is "POSIXct" "POSIXt".
The result in the database is  always 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

Here my R session:

```
library(XLConnect)
excel.file <- file.path("c:/path/test.xlsx")
elements <- readWorksheetFromFile(excel.file, sheet=1)
elements
       name nummer geburtsdatum
1     Anton      1   1967-05-11
2     Berti      2   1964-05-14
3     Conni      3   1967-01-01
4       Det      4   1967-01-01
5       Edi      5   1967-01-01
6 Fritzchen      6   1967-01-01

class(elements$geburtsdatum)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

library(RMySQL)
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), host = "127.0.0.1", user = "root", password = "xxxx", dbname = "test")
dbWriteTable(
+     conn = con,
+     name='testdaten3',
+     value = elements,
+     row.names = FALSE,
+     append = TRUE,
+     field.types = c(
+         name = "varchar(45)",
+         nummer = "tinyint",
+         geburtsdatum = 'timestamp'
+     )
+ )
[1] TRUE
--- end of R session ---
```

MySql database table testdaten3:

```
id      name    nummer  geburtsdatum
    1   Anton   1       0000-00-00 00:00:00
    2   Berti   2       0000-00-00 00:00:00
    3   Conni   3       0000-00-00 00:00:00
    4   Det     4       0000-00-00 00:00:00
    5   Edi     5       0000-00-00 00:00:00
    6   Fritzchen   6   0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

I already tried to convert the data like that:
elements$geburtsdatum <- format(elements$geburtsdatum,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
But the result was the same.
I use RStudio Version 1.1.456 with R 3.5.1 under Windows 8.1 and a MySql Server 5.6.

Can anybody help?

Kind regards

Goetz Edinger

Comment: Can you show an example of the actual raw data which you are inserting?  Furthermore, can you try doing a raw MySQL insert with this data, to see if that would work?

Comment: ... thank You for Your answer and the good ideas.
Indeed the following SQL produces the same result as my R code before:
insert into test.testdaten3 (name, nummer, geburtsdatum) VALUES ("Gedi", 7, '1964-05-14 01:01:01');  
The following SQL works fine:
insert into test.testdaten3 (name, nummer, geburtsdatum) VALUES ("Gedi", 7, FROM_UNIXTIME(1470762668));  
==>  '8', 'Gedi', '7', '2016-08-09 19:11:08'
Now I tried  to convert my date to '1964-05-14 01:01:01' and from there to UNIXTIME with:
elements$geburtsdatum <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(elements$geburtsdatum))
But that didn't work.

Comment: This isn't the insert which I had in mind.  How does `FROM_UNIXTIME` get involved here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You!! 
I found the mistake. If I use a date before '1970-01-01 01:00:01' the date is changed by the database to '0000-00-00 00:00:00'. So if I use a date which is equal to '1970-01-01 01:00:01' or newer the result is correct. It doesn't matter if I do it over R or over MySQL workbench. 
*** PROBLEM SOLVED ***

Answer (score 0):

From your example, it seems like geburtsdatum is just a date, with no time value. In that case, why not use as.Date(elements$geburtsdatum) to change it to a date type in your data frame and then use CONCAT to add it to the MySQL db?

Like this:

```
CONCAT(elements$geburtsdatum, " ", "00:00:00")
```

Basically, you are adding the birthday to a placeholder time value in order to make a timestamp.

Comment: Hello,

thank You for Your answer!
I believe to use as.Date(elements$geburtsdatum) is a part of the solution.
But I can`t change the data field from timestamp to date.
This is only a test database. In the real database there are more data fields of the type timestamp and the programming around is based on that. I must import data from excel into that database. It works fine if I use SQL. 
At least when I use FROM_UNIXTIME for the timestamp. Here an example: insert into test.testdaten3 (name, nummer, geburtsdatum) VALUES ("Gedi", 7, FROM_UNIXTIME(1470762668));

Kind regards

Goetz

Comment: I have edited my answer to use CONCAT, perhaps that will work for you